# Google Maps Static, can't insert custom icon

Tags: php, google-maps

Im using google maps static.
I want to have a custom icon in the center of the map.

This is how my request looks like:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=43.7000931135661900,7.2607183456420900&scale=2&size=300x200&sensor=false&maptype=roadmap&zoom=15&markers=icon:http://i.imgur.com/DOXAD.png

The image is fine, but no custom icon is displayed.
Not even if I encode the url of the icon as such: http%3A2F%2Fi.imgur.com%2FDOXAD.png|shadow:false

Any ideas? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=43.7000931135661900,7.2607183456420900&scale=2&size=300x200&sensor=false&maptype=roadmap&zoom=15&markers=icon:http://i.imgur.com/DOXAD.png|43.7000931135661900,7.2607183456420900
```

If you read the [google blog](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=43.7000931135661900,7.2607183456420900&scale=2&size=300x200&sensor=false&maptype=roadmap&zoom=15&markers=icon%3ahttp://i.imgur.com/DOXAD.png%7C43.7000931135661900,7.2607183456420900) and check how the image is done there, you can see, that each marker should have its center point and icon, which should be divided by |
In your case center point of map and center point of marker are the same, so you should copy LAT and LNG.

Answer (score 0):

Please remember to center your marker by providing LAN & LNG information with |.

Here is the sample.

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=43.7000931135661900,7.2607183456420900&scale=2&size=300x200&sensor=false&maptype=roadmap&zoom=15&markers=icon:http://i.imgur.com/DOXAD.png|43.7000931135661900,7.2607183456420900